# Mutable dictionary with fixed and ordered keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using OrderedDict for storage of some important data. I want to ensure, that accidentally inserted new key to this dictionary throws an exception but I want dict to be **mutable**. I want keys to be fixed (after created in `__init__`). Is it possible to do that with some library class? Or do I have to somehow implement new ordered class for this?

**Example:**

```
d = FixedOrderedDict( ( ("A", 1), ("B", 2) ) )

print d["A"]
# 1
d["A"] = 11
print d["A"]
# 11
d["C"] = 33
# throws exception
```

I was recommended to look up solution called **FrozenDict** but it makes dict read-only - values cannot be modified (throws exception when assigning new values). This is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I ran into a similar issue a while back. I had to subclass and override `__additem__()` IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a solution in the standard library (it's a rather specialized use case). You can however use [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (`collections.abc.MutableMapping` in 3.3 and onwards) to get most functionality for free. Give or take a few minor issues I may be overlooking right now, it's just:

```
from collections import MutableMapping, OrderedDict

class FixedOrderedDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._d = OrderedDict(*args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self._d:
            raise KeyError("Must not add new keys")
        self._d[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must not remove keys")

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)
```

Comment: Why not subclass `OrderedDict`, rather than use encapsulation?

Comment: @dano Because I'm not sure how to do that right and still get the mixins from `MutableMapping`. Multiple inheritance is hard (and the word you're looking for is *composition*). And it would only save four one-line methods (and pass some stupid type tests, I guess).

Comment: I agree with @delnan -- composition is the way to go here.

Comment: But if you only inherit from `OrderedDict` then you won't make the inheritance diagram any more complex than it already is (modulo the extra layer).

Comment: @holdenweb If I inherit only from `OrderedDict` I don't get the many [mixins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) from MutableMapping and either have to implement them manually (tedious and error prone) or severely restrict the convenience of the class.

Comment: The problem with inheriting only from `OrderedDict` is that you don't know (for certain) how the OrderedDict methods are implemented.  Even if they're implemented one way now, you can't guarantee that won't change in the future -- so you end up needing to override all of the ABC methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subclass of `dict` that allows you to freeze the keys at some point but allow the values to mutate? This one lets you freeze keys after filling, to allow more flexibility.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class FreezableDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(OrderedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self._frozen = False
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self and self._frozen:
            raise TypeError("No key additions once a FreezableDict is frozen!")
        return super(OrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
    def freeze(self):
        self._frozen = True

d = FreezableDict((("A", 1), ("B", 2)))

print d["A"]
d["C"] = "New Value"
d.freeze()
d["C"] = "Replacement"
print d["C"]
d["D"] = "This raises a TypeError exception"
```

Be careful, though, to remember that not all methods are wrapped here and it does not attempt to be a complete emulation of `OrderedDict` - the code assumes all inherited methods will operate correctly. For example, item deletion is currently still permitted even after freezing.

Answer (score 0):

There is one compact and fast solution for the cases when one have to create many dict-like objects with fixed collection of keys, which are identifiers:

```
from recordclass import make_dictclass

>>> MyDictLikeClass = make_dictclass(
                         "MyDictLikeClass", 
                         ("key1", "key2", "key3"))
>>> d = MyDictLikeClass(1,2,3)
>>> print(d["key1"], d["key2"], d["key3"])
1 2 3
>>> d["key1"] = -1
>>> d["wrong_key"] = 100
......
AttributeError
```

If one would like support both object-like and mapping-like api then there is another option:

```
from recordclass import make_dataclass

>>> MyDictLikeClass2 = make_dataclass(
                         "MyDictLikeClass2", 
                         ("key1", "key2", "key3"), mapping=True)
>>> d = MyDictLikeClass2(1,2,3)
>>> print(d["key1"], d["key2"], d["key3"])
1 2 3
>>> print(d.key1, d.key2, d.key3)
1 2 3
>>> d["key1"] = -1
>>> d["wrong_key"] = 100
......
AttributeError
>>> d.wrong_key = 100
......
AttributeError
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recordclass'`

Comment: One should first install `recordclass`: `pip3 install recordclass`